# fix order of citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, multiple-citations

The order of my citations in my original document text is messed up. For example, my text is like this:

```
Hello World is the best program \cite{helloWorld} and I use Latex \cite{latex}.....
....this is a new feature \cite{new}
```

while the citations are like this:

```
Hello World is the best program [11] and I use Latex [8].....
....this is a new feature [1]
```

and then in the .bib file I have some citations:

```
@article{speech,
    author    = "name",
    title     = "Title",
    pages = "13",
}
```

The citation where it shows [1] in the document is the one that I typed into my .bib file before typing anything else. However, now I have fixed the order of all citations in my bib file and arranged them in the order of how they should appear in the text. But still, **they aren't appearing from number 1 in the beginning.** How can i fix this? I have already tried recompling overleaf many times.

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,language=english, maxbibnames=99, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
...
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
...
  %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  %\bibliography{sample}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are mixing bibtex and biblatex commands.

Comment: Can you point me to a solution? @DG'

Comment: Get rid of `\bibliographystyle` and add the option `sorting=none` to biblatex

Comment: As DG' says and I mentioned under your [other recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571611/35864) you should not use `\bibliographystyle` when you load `biblatex`. The command will not work as expected (i.e. as with BIbTeX) and will throw an error instead. You also cannot use `\bibliography` in the document body when you use `biblatex`.

Comment: I have already tried removing ```\bibliographystyle``` and adding ```sorting=none``` as suggested in the link above but it doesn't fix the problem. @moewe

Comment: @x89 - As always: Please make a  [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows the issue at hand. Code fragments are not helpful!

Comment: Then please update your question with a small example document that shows what you are doing at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option `sorting` to `none`:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Delete all `.aux` files

Comment: I'm using overleaf and there are no aux files. I also tried removing the unused bib but it doesnt work either. Also tried copy pasting everything to a new project folder and files but still the same issue